# Why overflowing stack seems to cause program to hung and not segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, stack, stack-overflow

I'm trying to get a segmentation fault by overwriting the stack but the program seems to always hung no matter what.the code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("start\n");
    printf("Ending\n");
    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < 20; c++)
        array[c] = 5;
    printf("Done");
}
```

the program is build as:

```
    gcc -march=x86-64 -fno-stack-protector -gdwarf -o my_make my_make.c
```

I'm tying to get a core dump but can't see why the program just hung up without causing segmentation fault. running in gdb also seems to cause the program to hung so i have to terminate it.

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00005555555551ca in main () at my_make.c:10
10          for (c = 0; c < 20; c++)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [probably] compiling *without* optimization.

When you loop past the end of `array`, you are writing into the location where `c` is stored.

So, you're resetting the value of `c` to `5`.

So, the UB (undefined behavior) produces an infinite loop and *not* a segfault.

To *cause* a segfault, replace:

```
array[c] = 5;
```

With (e.g.):

```
array[c] = 150000;
```

Also, if that's not enough, increase the number of iterations. Replace the `for` loop with (e.g):

```
for (c = 0; c < 20000; c++)
```

---

Here's the complete code that gets a segfault on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    printf("start\n");
    printf("Ending\n");
    int array[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < 10000000; c++)
        array[c] = 15000;

    printf("Done\n");
}
```

Comment: your soultion does work for me too but this made me wonder why changing order of  ```int c = 0;``` and ```int array;``` doesn't solve the problem if there is no optimization wouldn't the position of the two in memory should be switched ie; solving the problem but it seems that ```int c``` to always be in higher memory location in gdb . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even _without_ optimization, a given compiler is free to order/reorder the stack frame any way it wishes. Thus, you can't rely on it [or even predict it].

Comment: Many years ago, a different compiler (for a Mac Classic), would order in a certain way. At a place where I worked, another programmer was _relying_ on the order: `struct foo { int count ; int arr[1]; }; int bigarray[100000];` so that `arr` would spill into `bigarray;` It "worked" until a new compiler rev. The compiler reversed the ordering and "broke" the broken code. I suggested a clean fix with: `struct order { struct foo foo; int bigarray[100000]; } force_order;`, but the other programmer felt insulted and just reversed the order in the source to "fix" it.

Comment: In fact, you could try that: `struct force { int c; int array[5] };` and, in `main`: `int main(void) { struct force var; for (var.c = 0;  var.c < 1000; var.c++) var.array[var.c] = 5; }`

Comment: thanks a lot this cleared the whole thing for me it caused a lot of pain when i was trying to see why the order didn't change .